# How to debug Heroku not performing external API requests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I deployed my app on heroku, its partially functioning as i have "server" side code that authenticates users with mongoDB atlas and performs api requests to Yelp's API. My app authenticates users just fine, but when i make a request to get nearby places,  I get this error in the console.

`GET https://my-first-trip.herokuapp.com/category/21.3420389/-157.7992015/pizza 503 (Service Unavailable)`

Here is the code for my `server.js` located in the root directory:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require('axios');
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const User = require('./models/user')
const session = require('express-session')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
const saltRounds = 6
const path = require('path')

mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI)

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"],
  credentials: true
}))
// app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: '',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false },
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.ATLAS_URI,
    // collectionName: 'users'
  })
}))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))

app.get("/category", (req, res) => {

  const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: '...' ,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': process.env.API_KEY
    }
  };

  axios(config)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(response.data)
      // console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.json(error) //this returns 'request failed with status code 400'
    });

});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

so the only route that doesnt work is `app.get("/category/:lat/:lng/:searchCategory"`. In the heroku cli, I get `code=H12` and `desc=Request timeout`. im pretty confident my yelp api query is a quick and inexpensive one. Im not sure how to debug this further.

EDIT: solved... my config var in heroku had extra quotes in my key. I entered `'key123'` instead of just `key123`. I wish there was a way to tell what my error was. status code 400 (failed request ) was too broad

Answer (score -1):

You can use Heroku Logging to find out about your error in detail:

I always use

```
heroku logs -n 1000 --tail
```

Or you can also use add-ons like [papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail)

Edit: Try hardcoding your API call variables.

Comment: can you elaborate more? i already used what you suggested to get the error code of `h12`

Comment: is yelp API query running on the local environment?

Comment: yes. everything was running as expected in local

Comment: when running the api route `"/category/:lat/:lng/:searchCategory"` it returns the error message 'request failed with  status code 400' as displayed with the heroku logs

Comment: try replacing cors object width default app.use(cors) and see if API return results without cors.

Comment: I tried using juse `app.use(cors())` but nothing changed. im assuming its a cross origin issue but im not 100%. i also tried using `node-fetch` instead of axios but it didnt work either.

Comment: console all your config variables and env variables, and check everything is correct. or you can try passing a hardcoded values in app.get URL also hardcode your env variable

Comment: hardcoding my api key worked thank you! now im just trying to figure out whats wrong with the env var setup

Comment: @benwl Can you give an example of what you did to fix this?

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi in the heroku dashboard, theres settings for putting in your `config var`. I accidentally put quotes around my api key like so `'key123'` removing it solved it for me eg `key123`